# pattern to avoid dynamic_cast

Tags: c++, oop, c++11

I have a class:

```
class A 
{
public:
  virtual void func() {…}
  virtual void func2() {…}
};
```

And some derived classes from this one, lets say B,C,D... In 95 % of the cases, i want to go through all objects and call func or func2(), so therefore i have them in a vector, like:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A> > myVec;
…
for (auto it = myVec.begin(); it != myVec.end(); ++it)
  (*it).func();
```

However, in the rest 5 % of the cases i want to do something different to the classes depending on their subclass. And I mean totally different, like calling functions that takes other parameters or not calling functions at all for some subclasses. I have thought of some options to solve this, none of which I really like:

- Use dynamic_cast to analyze subclass. Not good, too slow as I make calls very often and      on limited hardware
- Use a flag in each subclass, like an enum {IS_SUBCLASS_B, IS_SUBCLASS_C}. Not good as it doesnt feel OO.
- Also put the classes in other vectors, each for their specific task. This doesnt feel really OO either, but maybe I'm wrong here. Like:

  ```
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<B> > vecForDoingSpecificOperation;
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<C> > vecForDoingAnotherSpecificOperation;
  ```

So, can someone suggest a style/pattern that achieves what I want?

Comment: If you're dynamic casting to one fixed subhierarchy (ie. not doing a string of try-dynamic-casts), then go with it, because it is the clearest way of achieving this. Preferably add an interface, and dynamic cast to the interface.

Comment: It is not clear if you want to have a clear OO solution, or if you want to run your code and care for performance. Since copying `shared_ptr`s is cheap, just stuff it in different `std::vector`s as you suggested. You will have no branching inside loops then, which can be a plus point for performance.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Someone intelligent (unfortunately I forgot who) once said about OOP in C++: *The only reason for `switch`-ing over types (which is what all your suggestions propose) is fear of virtual functions.* (That's para-paraphrasing.) Add virtual functions to your base class which derived classes can override, and you're set.
Now, I know there are cases where this is hard or unwieldy. For that we have the visitor pattern.

There's cases where one is better, and cases where the other is. Usually, the rule of thumb goes like this:

- If you have a rather ***fixed set of operations***, but keep ***adding types***, use ***virtual functions***.
  Operations are hard to add to/remove from a big inheritance hierarchy, but new types are easy to add by simply having them override the appropriate virtual functions.
- If you have a rather ***fixed set of types***, but keep ***adding operations***, use the ***[visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)***.
  Adding new types to a large set of visitors is a serious pain in the neck, but adding a new visitor to a fixed set of types is easy.

(If both change, you're doomed either way.)

Comment: And no mention of the visitor pattern should be made without a link to [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/libs/variant/). :-]

Comment: The rule of thumb I use is: when facing the visitor pattern, consider using **another language**. Indeed, you're doing pattern matching, and functional languages excel at this.

Comment: Good general advice. But lets say I keep adding types. Virtual functions will still not help me resolve the subclass in a nice way?

Comment: @Frank: This is only a problem if, for every new type, you also need new operations. If so, you're in the "doomed" category. Chances are OOP is then not the best approach to do what you want.

Comment: @sbi: Well I found over the years  that we programmers are often in the doomed region as future requirements are too hard to predict

Comment: @sbi: This is the infamous (and dubiously named) [Expression Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_problem).

Comment: @MatthieuM. THis is not dubious: it arises when you are designing a language interpreter/compiler/whatever, and you keep adding expression types to your AST. In Haskell there is a way to alleviate it using algebraic tricks (the "free monad" of an algebra) and the very flexible type system. Eg. http://www.cs.ru.nl/~W.Swierstra/Publications/DataTypesALaCarte.pdf . Really, when the types don't change (or change slightly), you're better off using functional languages instead of C++

Comment: @AlexandreC.: Of course, most of the times, part of your program has stable types but needs new functionalities (because functionality means business) while another part has a pretty stable functionality set but you need to keep adding types (new protocol adaptors ?). So you're better off using a programming language that happens to provide support for both constructs, and interestingly, as demonstrated, C++ does because it supports *both* OO programming *and* Generic programming.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I strongly agree, since in practice, it is not as clear cut as "types don't change" or "actions don't change". Anyway, I find that very few languages provide support for such complex situations (with reasonable performance). C++ is one, Haskell is another. When types are (even roughly) fixed from the beginning, algebraic data types + pattern matching is *much* easier to work with than OOP and the visitor pattern. But again, you may not have the choice of the language.

Comment: @AlexandreC.: I agree about Haskell. I also need to catch up on `Rust`, but it seems they have a very ambitious project about types: a triad system based on classes (for encapsulation), interfaces (for polymorphism, similar to Haskell's typeclasses) and traits (for reuse). Since they also have generic functions I think once it is ready it should also be one of those languages that can handle this problem quite neatly. They even stole a bit of pattern matching with their `alt` statement.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Thanks for Rust, it seems indeed nice. A similar language would be D.

Answer (score 9):

According to your comments, what you have stumbled upon is known (dubiously) as the [Expression Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_problem), as expressed by Philip Wadler:

> The Expression Problem is a new name for an old problem. The goal is to define a datatype by cases, where one can add new cases to the datatype and new functions over the datatype, without recompiling existing code, and while retaining static type safety (e.g., no casts).

That is, extending both "vertically" (adding types to the hierarchy) and "horizontally" (adding functions to be overriden to the base class) is **hard** on the programmer.

There was a long (as always) discussion about it on Reddit in which I proposed a [solution in C++](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/mmrmj/the_expression_problem/c328mt3).

It is a bridge between OO (great at adding new types) and generic programming (great at adding new functions). The idea is to have a hierachy of pure interfaces and a set of non-polymorphic types. Free-functions are defined on the concrete types as needed, and the bridge with the pure interfaces is brought by a single template class for each interface (supplemented by a template function for automatic deduction).

I have found a single limitation to date: if a function returns a `Base` interface, it may have been generated as-is, even though the actual type wrapped supports more operations, now. This is typical of a modular design (the new functions were not available at the call site). I think it illustrates a clean design, however I understand one could want to "recast" it to a more verbose interface. `Go` can, with language support (basically, runtime introspection of the available methods). I don't want to code *this* in C++.

---

As already explained myself on reddit... I'll just reproduce and tweak the code I already submitted there.

So, let's start with 2 types and a single operation.

```
struct Square { double side; };
double area(Square const s);

struct Circle { double radius; };
double area(Circle const c);
```

Now, let's make a `Shape` interface:

```
class Shape {
public:
   virtual ~Shape();

   virtual double area() const = 0;

protected:
   Shape(Shape const&) {}
   Shape& operator=(Shape const&) { return *this; }
};

typedef std::unique_ptr<Shape> ShapePtr;

template <typename T>
class ShapeT: public Shape {
public:
   explicit ShapeT(T const t): _shape(t) {}

   virtual double area() const { return area(_shape); }

private:
  T _shape;
};

template <typename T>
ShapePtr newShape(T t) { return ShapePtr(new ShapeT<T>(t)); }
```

Okay, C++ is verbose. Let's check the use immediately:

```
double totalArea(std::vector<ShapePtr> const& shapes) {
   double total = 0.0;
   for (ShapePtr const& s: shapes) { total += s->area(); }
   return total;
}

int main() {
  std::vector<ShapePtr> shapes{ new_shape<Square>({5.0}), new_shape<Circle>({3.0}) };

  std::cout << totalArea(shapes) << "\n";
}
```

---

So, first exercise, let's add a shape (yep, it's all):

```
struct Rectangle { double length, height; };
double area(Rectangle const r);
```

---

Okay, so far so good, let's add a new function. We have two options.

The first is to modify `Shape` if it is in our power. This is source compatible, but not binary compatible.

```
// 1. We need to extend Shape:
  virtual double perimeter() const = 0

// 2. And its adapter: ShapeT
  virtual double perimeter() const { return perimeter(_shape); }

// 3. And provide the method for each Shape (obviously)
double perimeter(Square const s);
double perimeter(Circle const c);
double perimeter(Rectangle const r);
```

It may seem that we fall into the Expression Problem here, but we don't. We needed to add the perimeter for each (already known) class because there is no way to automatically infer it; however it did not require editing each class either!

Therefore, the combination of External Interface and free functions let us neatly (well, it is C++...) sidestep the issue.

`sodraz` noticed in comments that the addition of a function touched the original interface which may need to be frozen (provided by a 3rd party, or for binary compatibility issues).

The second options therefore is not intrusive, at the cost of being slightly more verbose:

```
class ExtendedShape: public Shape {
public:
  virtual double perimeter() const = 0;
protected:
  ExtendedShape(ExtendedShape const&) {}
  ExtendedShape& operator=(ExtendedShape const&) { return *this; }
};

typedef std::unique_ptr<ExtendedShape> ExtendedShapePtr;

template <typename T>
class ExtendedShapeT: public ExtendedShape {
public:
   virtual double area() const { return area(_data); }
   virtual double perimeter() const { return perimeter(_data); }
private:
  T _data;
};

template <typename T>
ExtendedShapePtr newExtendedShape(T t) { return ExtendedShapePtr(new ExtendedShapeT<T>(t)); }
```

And then, define the `perimeter` function for all those `Shape` we would like to use with the `ExtendedShape`.

The old code, compiled to work against `Shape`, still works. It does not need the new function anyway.

The new code can make use of the new functionality, and still interface painlessly with the old code. (*)

There is only one slight issue, if the old code return a `ShapePtr`, we do not know whether the shape actually has a perimeter function (note: if the pointer is generated internally, it has not been generated with the `newExtendedShape` mechanism). This is the **limitation** of the design mentioned at the beginning. Oops :)

(*) Note: painlessly implies that you know who the owner is. A `std::unique_ptr<Derived>&` and a `std::unique_ptr<Base>&` are not compatible, however a `std::unique_ptr<Base>` can be build from a `std::unique_ptr<Derived>` and a `Base*` from a `Derived*` so make sure your functions are clean ownership-wise and you're golden.

Comment: @ildjarn: Ah! Of course one should read *I don't want to code **this** in C++*, because adding introspection without language support is a pain in the ...

Comment: @MatthieuM. Could you please explain how this solves the problem if you have subclass specific functions? Like for a circle getRadius or getWidth for a rectangle?

Comment: @Minee: Subclass-specific functions cannot be accessed via run-time polymorphism on a base class; so it seems like a different question. You could add a `Shape::radius()`  method, but you'd have to decide what it means to ask the `radius` of a rectangle: maybe the method should return an optional, maybe you'd have inner/outer radiuses instead (which coincide for a circle), ... that's a domain decision that needs be solved prior to designing.